# Dynamically change repeater's data item

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, asprepeater

I have an `<asp:Repeater>` control that loads its data from a database.

To specify which column will be used where in the `.aspx` file, I use inside the Repeater's ItemTempate

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "column1")%>
```

Now when I need to make changes eg. I want another column instead of column1, I have to open Visual Studio, make the changes, publish the project again, and upload it to the server.

How can this control be more adjustable without having to change the source code each time?

Is there any other control that will do what I need better?

ASPX markup:

```
<table class="uk-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>Date 1</th>
        <th>Date 2</th>
        <th>State</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater2">
        <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr class="uk-table-middle">
                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"column1")%></span></td>
                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"column2")%></td>
                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"column3")%> </td>
                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"column4")%></span></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You could open the aspx page in a simple text editor and change `collumn1` to `collumn1a` and save. There is no need to publish the entire project for that. Just make sure that the new column exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a condition like the following and save your condition either in the database or an XML file or even in the web.config (on yours) and do the following. Don't forget to retrieve your condition out of the repeater if you wanna apply to all rows:

```
<% 
  var myCondition = true; // whatever it could be...
 %>
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater2">
    <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="uk-table-middle">
            <% if (mycondition){ %>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"column1")%></span></td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"column2")%></td>
            <% }else{ %>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"column2")%></td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"column1")%></span></td>
             <% } %>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"column3")%> </td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"column4")%></span></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater
```

Comment: can the condition be a string and contain the value of the collumn?

Comment: Definitely. Just change the "if (mycondition)" to:

 <% if (Eval("collumn1") == whather){ %>

Don't forget to convert the Eval binder to the proper type.

Comment: can this be more dynamic? for example if i need to add one more collumn? could the item template be an xml?

Comment: Definitely. Give me an sample of the data you are trying to append and I will tell you.

Comment: In the repeater now I have 4 collumns fixed. Lets say that i need to add one more collumn to show content of collumn7 field of the database. So i imagine that i will have to append this:   <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"collumn7")%></td>. but i  don't want to do this from the VS. I would like this to be like changing an xml.

Comment: I understand what you want to do. Just tell me what is condition? For instance, you could say if Column 2 is equal to "89" or whatever. What is the condition?

Comment: i don't have a condition. if a collumn will be changed will depend on the xml.

Comment: in my first comment when  i wrote condition i  was talking about the variable "mycondition"

Comment: You could apply whatever your logic is. Could you please tell me under what circumstances you want to switch them. Please give me a specific example.

Comment: Now the collumns have username, user email, date created and if the user is enabled. Later i might need to add the user's address to be shown permanently. after a while i might need to remove the date created.

Comment: If that's the case, I would personally prefer to update the code each time and by the way, there is no need to update the entire code each time. You may change the page code and only upload that particular page each time needed. 

Just update the page code and in Visual Studio, right click it and select "Publish YourPage.aspx" 

Don't forget to vote up if this is helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135534/discussion-between-athskar-and-amirhb).